# PHP INSERT Prepared statement not inserting with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I am attempting to create an `INSERT` statement using ajax and the query in a prepared statement form. I have never used AJAX with PDO before, so please excuse any ignorance.

The way this sits, I get the `alert(data);` error, but the alert pop-up just says "error | ". Is this referring to the javascript being incorrect or the php file? I believe it is the javascript because I am not even getting the php file to show up within my console network tab.

What is wrong within my `AJAX`?

```
<form method="POST" id="pdo-add">
    <input name="first" id="pdo-add-first" placeholder="First Name">
    <input name="last" id="pdo-add-last" placeholder="Last Name">
    <input name="product" id="pdo-add-product" placeholder="Product">
    <input name="add" type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

AJAX

```
$(function() {

   $("#pdo-add").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var add_first = $("#pdo-add-first").val();
    var add_last = $("#pdo-add-last").val();
    var add_product = $("#pdo-add-product").val();

    $.ajax({ 
        url: "pdoAddSend.php", 
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            "add_first": add_first,
            "add_last": add_last,
            "add_product": add_product
        },
        success: function (data) {
        //  console.log(data); // data object will return the response when status code is 200
            if (data == "Error!") {
                alert("Unable to insert product record!");
                alert(data);
            } else {
                //$("#newsletter-form")[0].reset();
                $('.announcement_success').html('Product Successfully Added!');
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + " | " + errorThrown);
            //console.log("error"); //otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
        }
    });
});
});
```

PHP

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$add_first = $_POST['add_first'];
$add_last = $_POST['add_last'];
$add_product = $_POST['add_product'];
try {
    $host = 'localhost';
    $name = '';
    $user = '';
    $password = '';

    $dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$name", $user, $password);

}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();

}

//if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
if(isset($add_first && $add_last && $add_product) {

    $stmt = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO users (first, last, product) VALUES (:first,:last,:product)");

    $stmt->bindParam(':first', $add_first);
    $stmt->bindParam(':last', $add_last);
    $stmt->bindParam(':product', $add_product);

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: change if(isset($_POST['add'])) { to your variables like `$add_first` or `$add_last` or `$add_product` it is not working because you dont have a `$_POST['add']`

Comment: So do this? `if(isset($add_first, $add_last, $add_product) { ...}`

Comment: use `&&` instead `,`

Comment: I don't think it is even getting to the php file, though. Nothing shows up in the network tab.

Comment: you can't use `first, last` without backticks, its a reserved word

Comment: remove comment on `.preventDefault();`

Comment: Thanks. I am getting this error now. `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in` for this  `if(isset($add_first && $add_last && $add_product) {`

Comment: can you update the OP?on what code you are using now

Comment: @guradio Sure. Question updated with current code.

Comment: `if (!empty($add_first) && !empty($add_last) && !empty($add_product)) {` do it like this...if you are sure that all the values should have values always.if there are empty among the 3 this will not insert

Comment: Ok it sends through now, but the page doesn't load the new record. I have to reload the page. Why is it doing that for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108462/discussion-between-guradio-and-becky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `if (!empty($add_first) && !empty($add_last) && !empty($add_product)) {` to check empty values
- Use `dataType json to return` array from database
- Insert Input dynamically in success of ajax

JS

```
$.ajax({
    url: "pdoAddSend.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        "add_first": add_first,
        "add_last": add_last,
        "add_product": add_product
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td><input name='id' value=" + data[i].id + " readonly=''></td><td><input name='first' value=" + data[i].first + "></td><td><input name='last' value=" + data[i].last + "></td><td><input name='product' value=" + data[i].product + "></td><td><input name='save' type='submit' value='Save'></td><td><input name='delete' type='submit' value='Delete'></td>");
            $("#tableid").append(tr);
        }
        console.log(data); // data object will return the response when status code is 200
        if (data == "Error!") {
            alert("Unable to insert product record!");
            alert(data);
        } else {
            //$("#newsletter-form")[0].reset();
            $('.announcement_success').html('Product Successfully Added!');
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + " | " + errorThrown);
        //console.log("error"); //otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better test these variables first, so that there is no "Undefined index" Notice occured.

And because you don't have a POST variable called add, if(isset($_POST['add'])) always be FALSE.

code here:

```
if(isset($_POST['add_product']) && isset($_POST['add_last']) && isset($_POST['add_product'])) {
    $add_first = $_POST['add_first'];
    $add_last = $_POST['add_last'];
    $add_product = $_POST['add_product'];
//then your db execute code here
}
```